# Números con comas en javascript y conservar dos digitos después del punto

Tags: javascript

estoy diseñando una calculadora de préstamos y pues necesito que salgan los resultados con comas y con dos dígitos después del punto decimal. Solo que cuando uso el método toString ya no me deja usar el método toFixed.
¿Me ayudan?

```
   for(i=2;i<=n2;i++){
        const localeStringd1 = d1.toLocaleString('en');
        d2=n4;
        const localeStringd2 = d2.toLocaleString('en');
        d3=(n4*(n3/100))+(d1*(n3/100));
        const localeStringd3 = d3.toLocaleString('en');
        SF=d1+d2+d3;
        const localeStringdSFF = SF.toLocaleString('en');
        document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML=document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML+
                **`<tr>
                    <td> ${i}</td>
                    <td> ${localeStringd1}</td>
                    <td> ${localeStringd2}</td>
                    <td> ${localeStringd3}</td>
                    <td> ${localeStringdSFF}</td>**
                </tr>`;
        d1=d1+d2+d3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si es lo que buscas, pero [.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) acepta los parámetros `minimumFractionDigits` y/o `maximumFractionDigits`.

```js
const numero = 1567.2666666;

const moneda = numero.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2 });

console.log(moneda);
```